# Windows 10 slow internet download, WSL 2.0 however is fast

Tags: windows-10, networking, download

I'm downloading files from certain hosts with different applications on a Windows 10 20H2 system.

On some hosts, not on all, I have just 20 % of my download speed.
I found out that regardless which application I use in Windows 10, my download speed is pretty slow. On other devices in the same network the download rate is high. Even in WSL 2 on the **same** system I get different download speeds - with a 100 % download speed rate.

I've tested with the following applications where I got the slow download rate:

1. Chrome
2. Firefox
3. Opera
4. Wget (in PowerShell)
5. Ubuntu in VirtualBox

I would have thought that it is the system in general or any network driver but as said I can download the same link with 100 % download rate on an Ubuntu in WSL 2. Also as mentioned any other device in the network is able to download the file with a maximun download rate.

Which really confused me is that WSL has a full speed access to the file where an Ubuntu system running in VirtualBox has not. But so far, I can't tell the difference between these connections.

So I tried to reset every connection on the Windows 10 system with no luck. Other than that I tried it via IPv4 and IPv6 separately, also with not luck. I thought it might have been TLSv 1.3 but it works like a charm on fast.com. I also disabled SmartScreen with no luck too.

How can I gain the full speed back? What might be the issue in downloading here?

Comment: Try running TCP/IP Reset on Windows 10.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer . Then test again.

Comment: @John tried it right now again with no success.

Comment: You may need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  Try with the Keep Everything option and everything will be retained.

Comment: @John this seems a bit like to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut for me _right now_ but I will keep it in mind, thanks for the suggestion. What really confuses me is that it is just related to few hosts and that it actually works like a charm on WSL 2.

Comment: Repair Installs are easy and simple to do and take less effort than troubleshooting a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @John finally found that needle. The tcp-autotuninglevel was set to disabled which led to that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `netsh int tcp show global` on the PowerShell in administrator context I was able to find out that the `autotuninglevel` was set to `disabled`.

After enabling it with the command `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal` I got my full speed back.

[See Microsoft documentation for further notes.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-Us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-performance-tuning-nics#review-and-configure-tcp-receive-window-autotuning-level)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Autotuning appears to be part of the WSL (or maybe Hyper-V) install. I have it "Normal" on my Hyper-V box and not even part of my VMware box (different machine

Answer (score 0):

Speedtest is good, also on the command line. But package downloads from ubuntu seem to be going really slow still. 40kb/s to 200kb/s. What the...

My actual internet speed is literally over 100 times that (200mbit bi-directional, which is slow because I'm working from home. It can be a full 10Gbit when at work).

I personally consider wsl (both one and two) to be broken.